# c# httpclient readbytearrayasync returns incomplete file on tasks

Tags: c#, httpclient

I use an instance of http client in two different tasks but when I call the ReadByteArrayAysnc method, it randomly returns only a part of the file, for example 68 bytes, even though the file is correct on the server. below the code

```
string requestUrl = ObtenerUrlPorRecibo(r.Nro_legaj, r.Nro_recibo);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
              
var response = await cliente.SendAsync(request);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    r.Archivo = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
}
else
{
    throw new Exception($"No se pudo obtner el archivo respuestad del server {response.StatusCode.ToString()}");
}
```

Comment: can you add more information about the data file, server type and implementation of `cliente`?

Comment: If you're trying to get a whole file from the server. is it possible you need to use `ReadAsStreamAsync` instead of `ReadAsByteArray`?